# Fixing invalid/broken Project Policy in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I've somehow caused a Project created in Phabricator to have an edit  policy which prevents me from administering membership, or making any other changes.

The Project History looks as follows:

- `<myusername>` created this project
- `<myusername>` added a member: `<myusername>`
- `<myusername>` changed the visibility from "All Users" to "Subscribers"
- `<myusername>` changed the edit policy from "All Users" to "Subscribers"
- `<myusername>` changed the join poliy from "All Users" to "Subscribers"
- `<myusername>` added members: `<memberA>`, `<memberB>`, `<memberC>`, `<memberD>`
- `<myusername>` changed the visibility from "Subscribers" to "`<ProjectName>` (Project)"

The end result is now I'm unable to Add Members or Edit the Project in any way.

The database format is not quickly discernible. I'm digging through sources but wondering if someone else already has been through this.

Is there some standard method for viewing/editing Phabricator ACLs? I'm reviewing documentation also but the info is sparse.

Thankful for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unlock the objects with `~/phabricator/bin/policy`:

```
NAME
    policy - manage policies

SYNOPSIS
    policy command [options]
        Administrative tool for reviewing and editing policies.


WORKFLOWS

    help [command]
    Show this help, or workflow help for command.

    show D123
    Show policy information about an object.

    unlock D123
    Unlock an object by setting its policies to allow anyone to view and
    edit it.


Use help command for a detailed command reference.
Use --show-standard-options to show additional options.
```

To get the PHID of a project use the Conduit method called `phid.lookup`:

`https://<phabricator-URI>/conduit/method/phid.lookup/`
[image]

[image]

Now you can use the PHID like this: 
`~> ./bin/policy show PHID-PROJ-mwyszvfopzei2xfnncda`

Comment: Success! Thank you for your help @OCram85!